# DownValue assignment using Apply

Tags: core-language, assignment

Why does assigning a DownValue using `Apply`, e.g.,

```
Remove[a]
index={3,4};
(a @@ index) = 5;
a @@ index
(*Set::write: Tag Apply in a @@ {3, 4} is Protected. >>*)
(*a[3,4]*)
```

not work, while an assignment such as

```
Remove[a]
a[Sequence @@ index] = 5
a @@ index
(*5*)
(*5*)
```

does?

Comment: `Set` holds its first argument, so you need to force the evaluation inside `Set`. To work in all cases (including the case when `a` has been already defined on that index), I'd do something like `Hold@@index/.Hold[inds__]:>Set[a[inds],5]`. This seems to be a duplicate of at least one similar question, but I can't find it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The behaviour we see here is due to `Set` performing limited evaluation of its left-hand-side prior to the assignment.

**`Set` Evaluates the Left-Hand-Side**

Despite the fact that `Set` has the attribute `HoldFirst`, it performs a special kind of evaluation upon its left-hand-side prior to performing the assignment.  Specifically, if the left-hand-side has a head and parts, then that head and those parts are evaluated -- but no further rules are applied to the result.

Here is a generic example illustrating this behaviour:

```
ClearAll[f1, f2, a1, a2]
f1 = f2;
f2[___] := Print@"f2 evaluated!"
a1 = 1; a2 = 2;
f1[a1 + a2] = 999;
??f2
```

[image: INFORMATION screenshot]

Observe how even though the `Set` expression was assigning to `f1[a1 + a2]`, the resulting definition is actually attached to `f2[3]`.  `f1` was evaluated to `f2` and `a1 + a2` was evaluated to `3`.  But also note that the pre-existing definition that matches `f2[3]` was *not* invoked, and nothing was printed.

In contrast, if the left-hand-side has no parts, it is *not* evaluated:

```
ClearAll[a, b]
a = b;
a = 3;
??a
```

[image: INFORMATION screenshot]

```
??b
```

[image: INFORMATION screenshot]

**The Case At Hand**

Let us now apply this knowledge to the case at hand.

For `(a @@ index) = 5`, `Set` performs the limited evaluation upon the left-hand-side.  `index` is replaced with `{3, 4}` to produce `a @@ {3, 4}` which is to say `Apply[a, {3, 4}]`.  As noted above, the normal definition of `Apply` is not expanded so this is the final left-hand-side.  Next, `Set` attempts to assign `5` to this expression.  Since `Apply` is protected, the attempt fails with an error message.

Now, `a[Sequence @@ index] = 5`.  By construction, the head `a` is inert so it evaluates to itself.  `Sequence @@ index` is evaluated to produce `Sequence[3, 4]`.  Since `a` does not have the `SequenceHold` attribute, the `Sequence` head is stripped yielding a final left-hand-side of `a[3, 4]`.  This is a valid and unprotected assignment target, so the assignment succeeds.

**Why Does `Set` Behave Like This?**

It is necessary for `Set` to perform at least some evaluation of the left-hand-side for otherwise expressions like `x[i, j-1] = y` would be far less useful.  We want to have the indices `i` and `j-1` evaluated.  On the other hand, full evaluation of the left-hand-side would mean that we could never reassign a variable after its initial assignment because it would disappear from the left-hand-side by evaluation.  Thus, we have these arcane rules of partial evaluation.  Most of the time, these rules just "do the right thing".  But occasionally, like for the present question, the subtleties of the rules are observable.

**Workaround**

One way to work-around the present problem is as follows:

```
(a[##] = 5) &@@ index

a @@ index
(* 5 *)

(a[##] = 6) &@@ index

a @@ index
(* 6 *)
```

The technique works even if a prior assignment has been performed.

Comment: +1. I think I will point to a similar discussion I had in my post answering [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7408310/unwanted-evaluation-in-assignments-in-mathematica-why-it-happens-and-how-to-de).

Comment: Also somewhat related: [(5846756)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5846756/618728)

Answer (score 6):

Evaluation happens too late, but you can fix it by forcing evaluation first:

```
Remove[a]
index = {3, 4};

Evaluate[a @@ index] = 5;
a @@ index
```

> 5

This can only be done on the initial definition though.  After that

```
a[Sequence @@ index] = 6;
a @@ index
```

> 6