# Confusion about HoldFirst attribute of Set

Tags: assignment, hold, attributes

`Set` has the attribute `HoldFirst`.
Expectedly the following does not work, i.e. it does not assign the OwnValue of 3 to x:

```
In[1]:= {x, y}[[1]] = 3

During evaluation of In[1]:= Set::setps: {x,y} in the part assignment is not a symbol.

Out[1]= 3
```

However, the following **does** work:

```
In[2]:= {f, g}[[1]][x_] = x^2

Out[2]= x^2
```

with the result

```
?f
Global`f
f[x_]=x^2
```

Can anyone explain that?

Comment: Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/148387/part-not-behaving-the-way-i-expect-it-to/148388#148388

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is not related to `Set` in general but to how `Set` works with `Part` on a left hand side.

Following `Set::setps` message documentation

> This message is generated when a ***part assignment*** is used for the value of an expression other than a symbol.
>
> ***Part assignments*** are implemented only for parts of the value of a symbol.

Shortly

```
Part[(*something*), (*spec*)] = (*value*)
```

will only work if `(*something*)` is a symbol so that `Set` can do in place modification of a part of that symbol. ( how much 'in place' is that is a different topic and I'm not competent to elaborate)

The second example is not a ***Part assignment***, because the head of the *lhs* is not `Part` but whole expression: `Part[{f, g}, 1]`.

`HoldFirst` does not mean it will not be evaluated ever. It is used by `Set` to detect e.g. whether it is an event of a ***Part assignment***.

Answer (score 10):

Kuba's answer explains why the first form does *not* work, but it does not address why the second form *does* work.  That has been discussed in other questions

- [DownValue assignment using Apply](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/63015/121)
- [Why is the first argument of the SetDelayed evaluated?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/95557/121)
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/5846756/618728
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/7408310/618728

One can see that the *head* of the left-hand-side is evaluated in each of these cases:

```
ClearAll[a, b, c, x]
x = {a, b, c};

(# & @@ x)[1] = 1;
Extract[x, 2][1] = 2;
Last[x][1] = 3;

Definition[a, b, c]
```

> ```
> a[1] = 1
>
> b[1] = 2
>
> c[1] = 3
> ```

Additionally the arguments are evaluated as seen in:

```
pats = {i_, j_, k_};

Last[x][First[pats]] = i^2;

c[4]
```

> ```
> 16
> ```

The LHS is not *fully* evaluated before assignment however; instead a special evaluation sequence is used.

With the definitions above in place if one separately evaluates:

```
Last[x][Last@pats]
```

> ```
> k_^2
> ```

And if one manually attempts assignment to this it does not work:

```
k_^2 = 4;
```

> ```
> Set::write: Tag Power in k_^2 is Protected. >>
> ```

However assigning to the compound expression:

```
Last[x][Last@pats] = 5;

c[1000]
```

> ```
> 5
> ```

```
? c
```

> ```
> c[1] = 3
>
> c[k_] = 5
> ```

Comment: I guess Kuba's answer had a hint in the right direction for the second part but your answer made the second part much clearer, thanks. In the end it's all about how the lhs is evaluated before assignment. To be honest, in such cases I usually just try different things using simple examples, since I don't see how to extract such information from the documentation.